# Suggestion to make a massive insert

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have the tables below:

```
tb_profile   tb_mbx     tb_profile_mbx   tb_profile_cd
id           id         id_profile       id_perfil 
cod_mat      mbx        id_mbx           id_cd (matches id_mbx)
concil                  bp
                        masc
```

- I need to create a query that when validating that the id_cd 1,2,4,5
  and 6 exists in tb_profile_cd, perform an insert in the
  tb_profile_mbx table with the cod_matrix parameters of the tb_profile
  table.
- Remembering that each concil has its ID in the tb_mbx table and a
  concil has many cod_mat.
- Another point is that the concil id_mbx represents the id_cd of the
  tb_profile_cd table.
- One more point is that as I said above, that a concil has many
  cod_mat. I have around 20 thousand records for each concil.

For my need, try to consult the query below, but Oracle returned an error:

```
insert into tb_profile_mbx values (seq_profile_mbx.nextval,
     (select id from tb_profile where concil like '%NEXXERA%')
    ,(select id from tb_mbx where mbx like '%NEXXERA%')
    ,null
    ,null);
```

> ORA-01427: single line subquery returns more than one line

Would there be another way to do this query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `insert into tb_profile_mbx select seq_profile_mbx.nextval, id, ... from tb_profile ...`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert all matching combinations of matches using:

```
insert into tb_profile_mbx (id_profile, id_mbx) 
    select p.id, m.id
    from tb_profile p join
         tb_mbx m
         on p.concil like '%NEXXERA%' and m.mbx like '%NEXXERA%';
```

I would recommend running the `select` to see if it returns the values you want.

You only show two columns for `tb_profile_mbx`, so I've only included two columns in the `insert`.

Comment: The select returned the IDs correctly, but for me to perform the Insert, I need to include two more fields that are always null, example:
`id_perfil, id_mbx, bp(null), masc(null);`

Comment: @devnan . . . List the columns in the `INSERT` and just add `NULL` to the corresponding position in the `SELECT`.